# Flurry Analytics not logging Unhandled Exceptions

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, flurry

I've been using Flurry Analytics for Windows Phone for quite some time in my app now. Normal logging works perfectly but I've never been able to capture an unhandled exception with the SDK for WP8 v3.1.1 (which is the latest version at present).

I've followed the instructions on rigging up the SDK in my App.xaml.cs file:

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
        Debugger.Break();
    }
    else
    {
        FlurryWP8SDK.Api.LogError("Application_UnhandledException", e.ExceptionObject);
    }
}
```

Windows Phone Dev Center tells me my app, through its "Crash reports" graph, that the app is crashing occasionally, but in Flurry "Technical" > "Errors" I never see a single error logged.

Anyone have any ideas why I'm not getting this valuable feedback through Flurry? I was hoping to use it to highlight any issues that might get past testing.

To clarify... I'm trying to log exceptions from the live app, out in the wild, not from my local dev / debugging environment.

Also to confirm, the Flurry session is being started as recommended:

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    FlurryWP8SDK.Api.StartSession(AppSettings.FlurryApiKey);
}

private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    FlurryWP8SDK.Api.StartSession(AppSettings.FlurryApiKey);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Okay, here are two ideas. Is there a Flurry sessions started? If not - this will not work. Everything should happen in a session. Also, if you don't mark the error as handled, and the app exits immediately, there is a chance that Flurry didn't get enough time to store the error info.

Comment: @yasen - Thanks for your ideas - very much appreciated... There's the recommended code in use to start the session, and indeed analytics are being captured. But saying that, I only know there are crashes and nothing about them so the scenario you describe could happen I guess. Is there some way to mark an exception as handled in Application_UnhandledException? Seems a bit pointless of Flurry to recommend adding their code to Application_UnhandledException if it can't actually capture anything there. I wonder if there's a better way to wrap their code so it can store the error info in time.

Comment: BTW: I've also opened a support ticket with Flurry about this issue, but still no response from them as of yet. I was just hoping someone had encountered the problem and found a workaround. Maybe I should be asking a question about alternatives to Flurry that will actually log exceptions successfully. Could be that Flurry just isn't that popular on WP.

Comment: To test Flurry, you can enable error logging when debugging and make a button or something always throws an exception. See if they log it (test it without internet, so that you can see it in a file in isolated storage). The args of the UnhandledException event have a Handled property. Just set it to true and the exception will be ignored (the app won't be closed and you won't get a crash report in the store). Check if marking it as handled makes Flurry work.

Comment: @yasen - I can confirm that no session file appears in the Flurry folder even when I set Handled = true. I do see a file appear for FlurryWP8SDK.Api.LogEvent calls, just not FlurryWP8SDK.Api.LogError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Flurry never got back to me with a fix so I ended up replacing Flurry with [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com/) for catching unhandled exceptions. BugSense has been working perfectly, giving me meaningful exception reports I can action.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add EndSession() method:

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
        Debugger.Break();
    }
    else
    {
        FlurryWP8SDK.Api.LogError("Application_UnhandledException", e.ExceptionObject);
        FlurryWP8SDK.Api.EndSession();
    }
}
```

FlurryWP8SDK.Api.EndSession() call forces session file creation, so crash will be stored on device.

Answer (score -1):

Try this It Would work.

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
                FlurryWP8SDK.Api.LogError("Application_UnhandledException", e.ExceptionObject);
                Debugger.Break();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to catch exception details in the live app, not during development. Sorry - I should have been clearer.

Comment: @Gavin It would work if you remove the `if (Debugger.IsAttached)` part. You should always catch all exceptions! I'd suggest you subscribe to the UnhandledException event, call Flurry's LogError and then mark the exception as handled.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I thought Debugger.IsAttached would always be false when the app is live on peoples devices? I thought this check was to allow debugging from Visual Studio, via Debugger.Break(), when testing against the device / emulator, and in which case I'm not interested in logging the exception with Flurry. I'm only interested in logging live errors out in the wild but the code above suggests I'm only going to log errors when a Debugger IsAttached.

Comment: @yasen - That's basically what my original code does, so no progress. Unless on live Windows Phones there's always a debugger attached, which sounds wrong?